# http request is not execute in refreshing page

Tags: angularjs, http, post, request

my http request is not working after my token is expired in first refresh but in second refresh is work fine, but the function is executing fine what have done wrong. i work in angular frame

```js
$http({
    url: "http://localhost/ArisSystem/api/system/subsystem",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    ContentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    params: {
        parentId: $scope.systemIdToLoad
    },
    headers: authHeaders
}).then(function (response) {
    $scope.subsystem = response.data;
}), function (xhr, status, error) {
    if (refreshtoken && xhr.status === 401) {
         $scope.refreshlocal();
    }
}
$scope.refreshlocal = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/ArisSystem/login",
        data: {
            refresh_token: refreshtoken,
            grant_type: 'refresh_token'
        },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        ContentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        success: AjaxSucceeded,
        error: AjaxFailed
    })
    function AjaxSucceeded(response) {
        localStorage.setItem('accessToken', response.access_token);
        localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', response.refresh_token);
        refreshtoken = localStorage.getItem('refreshToken');
        accesstoken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
        authHeaders.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + accesstoken;
    }
    function AjaxFailed(err, response) {
        window.location.href = "login.html"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your `then` function. The error-callback is outside the argument list. Instead it should be this:

```
$http({
...
}).then(function (response) {
    $scope.subsystem = response.data;
}, function (xhr, status, error) {
    if (refreshtoken && xhr.status === 401) {
        $scope.refreshlocal();
    }
});
```

I simply moved the `)` from the 5th line back after the error-callback function.

That ought to do it. I'd suggest you do change the second request from  `$.ajax` to use the  `$http` service as well, just to keep your code consistent.